# CSS Clear within float based columns?

Tags: css, css-float

I'm floating a sidebar to the left of the main content panel. Then inside that panel, I have a number of boxes, which are floated and cleared in order to create a sort of grid (it's a "my account" page, with various boxes containing things like orders, edit details etc). The problem is that the boxes inside the content div are clearing against the sidebar, as opposed to just the other boxes in that div. There's a link to an image below if that explanation was confusing:

[image]

Has anyone come across this before, and if so, do you know a fix for it? I'm probably going about this the wrong way, but I learnt CSS almost entirely from trial and error, so my knowledge of the theory of it is most likely woefully lacking.

Comment: Can you please post a demo using jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I'll try get some sample code up later. For now, a simple, if not very elegant fix was to add a second div inside the content div, with a float:left attribute on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the content panel isn't floated, any elements inside will clear the sidebar float. Easy solution would be to float the content panel. Since you haven't posted html/css it's hard to really see the issue, though, and provide any suggestions for if you don't want to float the content panel.

[Before](http://jsfiddle.net/7JwGL/3/)

[After](http://jsfiddle.net/7JwGL/2/)

Comment: Floating the content panel seems like the solution I'm looking for. However, doing so messes with the layout, forcing the content panel underneath the navigation box. That's a different issue though, so I'll accept your answer :)

Comment: It would help seeing the full layout in a future question if you don't mind, so we can all take a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would want to selectively clear the floats on one side, like `clear: right;` or `clear: left;`

I haven't run into that issue though so I'm not sure.

Answer (score -2):

You could try display:inline-block.  But it is a new feature not that well supported.  CSS is a dog, I just change my designs to fit in with what it can do.

https://learn.shayhowe.com/html-css/positioning-content/

Or, just use tables.  Tables just work.

Comment: All browsers support `inline-block` including IE back to version 8. But this question is seven and a half years old including the accepted answer so I don't know why you replied.